# DateTimePicker in WPF does not change date when pressing spinner buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, xceed

I am using Xceed's WPF Extended Library and I am using the DateTimePicker control. I have overridden the styling for the control to primarily change the style of the repeat buttons on the side.
However, now when I press them they don't increment/decrement the date-time as expected. Why is this happening?

**The control on my UserControl:**

```
 <xctk:DateTimePicker Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerStyle}" FontSize="18" ShowDropDownButton="False" IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding Path=Start}">
        </xctk:DateTimePicker>
```

**DateTimePickerStyle**

```
<Style x:Key="DateTimePickerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource WhiteColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>

        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xctk:DateTimePicker}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="firstContentColumn" Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="secondContentColumn" Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />

                            <!--<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Text}" IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>-->
                            <Grid x:Name="gridContent" Grid.Column="1" Width="50">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_IncreaseButton" Background="{StaticResource NavyBlueBrush}">
                                    <RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Path Data="M0,3C0,3 0,4 0,4 0,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 7,4 7,4 7,4 7,3 7,3 7,3 6,3 6,3 6,3 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,1 5,1 5,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 2,1 2,1 2,1 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,3 1,3 1,3 0,3 0,3z" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteColorBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="7"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                                </RepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_DecreaseButton" Width="50" Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource NavyBlueBrush}">
                                    <RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Path Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z"  Fill="{StaticResource WhiteColorBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="7"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </RepeatButton.ContentTemplate>
                                </RepeatButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlMouseOverBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlSelectedBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ControlDisabledBackgroundKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type themes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" SourceName="PART_IncreaseButton" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="PART_IncreaseButton">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Path Data="M0,3C0,3 0,4 0,4 0,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 7,4 7,4 7,4 7,3 7,3 7,3 6,3 6,3 6,3 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,1 5,1 5,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 2,1 2,1 2,1 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,3 1,3 1,3 0,3 0,3z" Focusable="False" Fill="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=GlyphDisabledForegroundKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type themes:ResourceKeys}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="7"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" SourceName="PART_DecreaseButton" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" TargetName="PART_DecreaseButton">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Path Data="M0,1C0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 3,0 3,0 3,0 3,1 3,1 3,1 4,1 4,1 4,1 4,0 4,0 4,0 7,0 7,0 7,0 7,1 7,1 7,1 6,1 6,1 6,1 6,2 6,2 6,2 5,2 5,2 5,2 5,3 5,3 5,3 4,3 4,3 4,3 4,4 4,4 4,4 3,4 3,4 3,4 3,3 3,3 3,3 2,3 2,3 2,3 2,2 2,2 2,2 1,2 1,2 1,2 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,1 0,1z" Focusable="False" Fill="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=GlyphDisabledForegroundKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type themes:ResourceKeys}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="7"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ButtonSpinnerLocation" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="firstContentColumn" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="secondContentColumn" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="gridContent" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**How to control looks on screen**
[image]

Comment: is it that you Bind to the `Text` of the DateTimePicker, instead of the `Value` Property?

Comment: Your template is supposed to include a `ButtonSpinner` but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the control are you using? It is a known issue with xceed DateTimePicker if the date is selected using the calendar. They have to enter first or untill the picker has lost focus. The issue was fixed in later version than v3.5

Comment: Using 3.7, I've also turned off the calander.